# Is there a kubectl command to create kafka topic without using import yaml file option?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubectl, strimzi

I have deployed strimzi kafka on kubernetes and I have kube setup in my local as well. But each time I want a new topic in kafka, I need to create one by importing the yaml file via rancher and provide the topic name.

Is there a way to create a kafka topic directly via kubectl command?

These are the commands I use to run kafka:

`Producer: kubectl run kafka-producer1 -ti --image=strimzi/kafka:0.18.0-kafka-2.4.0  --rm=true --restart=Never -- bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 11.23.41.32:31025 --topic topic-name`

`Consumer: kubectl run kafka-consumer1 -ti --image=strimzi/kafka:0.18.0-kafka-2.4.0 --restart=Never -- bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 11.23.41.32:31025 --topic topic-name --from-beginning`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps to create topic via commandline : (assumed zookeeper running on port 2181 and kafka server on 9092)

1. Get inside the kafka pod by using this command

`kubectl exec -it kafka-pod-name -- /bin/bash`

2. Create the topic by using below command

`kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic topic-name --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3`

3. you can verify the message produce and consume using below commands-

a) produce-->

1. `kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic <topic-you-created-before>`
2. provide some message

b) consume--> `kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic audit --from-beginning`

you can see the message(provided by producer) here

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use the `KafkaTopic` resource:

```yaml
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1
kind: KafkaTopic
metadata:
  name: my-new-topic
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-cluster
spec:
  replicas: 3
  partitions: 10
EOF
```

`kubectl get kafkatopics.kafka.strimzi.io`

```sh
NAME           CLUSTER      PARTITIONS   REPLICATION FACTOR
my-new-topic   my-cluster   10           3
```

Comment: Requires the Strimzi operator

Comment: Though not generic one. But, good one.

Answer (score 1):

This is the  one of the command for creating the topic with help of kafka connect and kubectl

```
kubectl exec -it <kafka-connect-service-name>  -c <cluster-ip> -n labkafka -- kafka-topics --create --topic <topic_name> --bootstrap-server <bootstrap-server>
```

Comment: What if you're not running Connect?

Answer (score 0):

You could run `kafka-topics` just like you are producing and consuming

```
kubectl run ... kafka-topics --create ...
```